# Build AMI in packer including modified snapshot with packer

Tags: amazon-web-services, packer

I'd like to build an AMI with two block devices, which are modified during provisioning. When I create an AMI with packer, it doesn't seem to take new snapshots of the block devices. Is there a way to force this?

My template is

`{
  "builders": [{
    "type": "amazon-ebs",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "source_ami": "ami-08842d60",
    "instance_type": "m4.2xlarge",
    "security_group_id": "<redacted>",
    "subnet_id" : "<redacted>",
    "ssh_username": "ec2-user",
    "ssh_pty": true,
    "ami_name": "testing {{timestamp}}",
    "ami_block_device_mappings": [{
      "device_name": "/dev/sdf",
      "volume_type": "gp2",
      "volume_size": 100,
      "delete_on_termination": true,
      "encrypted": true
    }, {
      "device_name": "/dev/sdg",
      "volume_type": "gp2",
      "volume_size": 100,
      "delete_on_termination": true,
      "encrypted": true
    }]
  }]
}`

Comment: If this question doesn’t contain any code, the answer is going to be useless for future visitors as well. Please add the relevant code to your question to avoid having it closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue was that I was using `ami_block_device_mappings` instead of `launch_block_device_mappings`. The former are added only to the AMI and not the launch instance. `launch_block_device_mappings` are added to the instance from which the AMI is built, and will be snapshotted and added to to the registered AMI.